# Is there a switch to turn off LaTeX counters from inside a box?

Tags: macros, boxes, counters

I know that `amsmath` typesets at least twice its material, the first one for measurement and that it takes measures (sic) to avoid some counters being updated twice.

Is there a switch a macro writer could use to inform LaTeX not to update counters (which are global in LaTeX) when it is needed to typeset some unknown contents `#1` inside a box, which will be discarded later?

---

update from info gathered from `egreg`'s answer and a (belated) look in the sources. It is not as I said above that `amsmath` avoids for *some* counters to be updated; it avoids it for all, because it uses a list of *all* counter names which is kept up-to-date by the latex kernel, and designed to allow anyone using it to do things with **all** these names. The conclusion is thus that `amsmath` defines the macro pair `\savecounters@/\restorecounters@` because it needs the functionality, but that anyone can copy their definitions (`\savecounters@` defines what `\restorecounters@` will do) and use them with the same effect without having to load `amsmath` or even any portion of it. Just replace `\@nx` by `\noexpand`.

Comment: `\ifmeasuring@` is true in the first step and false during actual typesetting. However subtle problems can arise, if the counter's value changes from one to two digits. Can you give an example?

Comment: @egreg I mentioned `amsmath` for background, I am asking for a switch provided by the LaTeX kernel. I have not looked at what exactly `amsmath` does to avoid counters being updated twice, I am asking if LaTeX provides now a way to do that.

Comment: @egreg the reason I am asking is that I just worked on this [anwer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135080/4686) and my method uses two preliminary renderings of the unknown argument, which may contain macros updating counters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is basically what `amsmath` does for avoiding the problem of stepping counters twice when measuring. The changes to the counters' values should take place during the measuring phase, or there's the risk that a change from one to two digits ruins the measures made.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}

\newcounter{xyz}
\newcommand{\doxyz}{\stepcounter{xyz}--\thexyz--}

\makeatletter
\newdimen\jfbu@width
\newcommand{\processtwice}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \savecounters@
  % here we do the measurement
  \sbox\z@{#1}%
  \global\jfbu@width=2\wd\z@
  % and we restore the counters' values
  \restorecounters@
  \endgroup
  \colorbox{yellow}{\makebox[\jfbu@width]{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\processtwice{\doxyz}

\processtwice{\doxyz}

\end{document}
```

As you see, `#1` is evaluated twice, but the counter is stepped only the right number of times.

[image]

Comment: ok, so I ended up looking in `amsmath` and `latex` and I am very surprised that `amsmath` just uses the `\cl@@ckpt` thing in a simple way; it didn't have to tap into `\newcounter` etc... surprising really that `\savecounters@` and `restorecounters@` are provided by `amsmath`, and not from the **latex kernel itself**. The good news is thus that a macro writer only has to steal the macros from `amsmath`.