# Vertically aligning minipages, subfigures, and subtables (not with baseline)

Tags: captions, vertical-alignment, minipage, subcaption

### The goal

My goal is to align side-by-side `figure`s, `table`s, and text in minipages according to the top, middle and bottom of the *largest such `minipage`*. This makes it different (I believe) from the related links and references at the bottom, which detail the *baseline* of the surrounding text. I don't know which figure is largest.

For example, consider the following figure:

[image]

Notice that `A` and `C` are aligned to the bottom *of `C`* and that the fourth image is aligned to the middle of `C`, the largest image.

The algorithm for this is quite straightforward:

- put all of the `minipage` environments in a box, and measure the height
- then set each `minipage` using `\begin{minipage}[b][MAX HEIGHT][<alignment>]` so that each one is 'anchored' to the bottom, each one has the same height (cruicial), and then the position of each contents can be specified (`t`, `c`, or `b`).

### The problem

The problem I'm having is when I try to `caption` these objects, the numbering falls down. I get, for example, the following:

[image: screenshot]

Having read [Is there a switch to turn off LaTeX counters from inside a box?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135412/is-there-a-switch-to-turn-off-latex-counters-from-inside-a-box), I thought I could fix it with `\savecounters@` and `restorecounters@`.

### The question

How can I modify my code so that the numbering of both `figure`s and `subfigure`s is as expected? Solutions would hopefully scale naturally to tables.

I'm very open to alternatives that accomplish the same idea; I have tried with the [`adjustbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package, for example, but no luck so far.

### The MWE

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe=true,textwidth=12cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{environ}

\newsavebox{\vabox}
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{verticallyaligned}{%
    % temporarily set \vamaxheight to nothing during the measurements
    \let\vamaxheight\relax
    % temporarily disable figure numbering
    \savecounters@
    % measure the height of the body
    \begin{lrbox}{\vabox}
        \BODY%
    \end{lrbox}%
    % turn figure numbering back on
    \restorecounters@
    % set the height of the minipage box
    \newlength{\vamaxheight}
    \setlength{\vamaxheight}{\ht\vabox}
    % output the body, which now contains the new height :)
    \noindent\makebox[\linewidth][c]{\mbox{}\hfill\BODY\hfill\mbox{}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{verticallyaligned}
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}[b][\vamaxheight][b]{.10\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \captionof{figure}{}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b][\vamaxheight][t]{.15\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \captionof{figure}{}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b][\vamaxheight][t]{.20\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b][\vamaxheight][c]{.10\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b][\vamaxheight][t]{.20\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{minipage}%
\end{verticallyaligned}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \begin{verticallyaligned}
        \begin{subfigure}[b][\vamaxheight][t]{.10\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b][\vamaxheight][t]{.15\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{}
        \end{subfigure}%
    \end{verticallyaligned}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \begin{verticallyaligned}
        \begin{subfigure}[b][\vamaxheight][c]{.10\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b][\vamaxheight][c]{.15\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{}
        \end{subfigure}%
    \end{verticallyaligned}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

## References

- [Understanding minipages - aligning at top](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34166/understanding-minipages-aligning-at-top)
- [minipage environment with bottom-aligned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132080/minipage-environment-with-bottom-aligned)
- [Is there a switch to turn off LaTeX counters from inside a box?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135412/is-there-a-switch-to-turn-off-latex-counters-from-inside-a-box)

Comment: Have you looked at `floatrow`?

Comment: It has been my experience that centered boxes aren't always precisely centered.  Anyway, one can determine the distance from the top to the baseline (height) and the distance from the baseline to the bottom (depth) using \settoheight or \settodepth or sometimes simply \height of \depth.  For example, \raisebox{-\height}{...} will align tops and \raisebox{\depth}{...} will align bottoms of pretty much anything.

Comment: @cfr I'm open to the idea--I need to be able to specify width, vertical alignment, have subfigures, subtables, and to be able to put figures next to tables and text

Comment: @JohnKormylo I'd very much like to see a demonstration in the context of my example code, if you have the time

Comment: Sorry, it was late at night (for me) when I first scanned this.  I take it you don't want to align the captions, just the figures.  The obvious solution is to use tabulars instead of \subcaption.  (If you want the subcaptions to show up in the \listoffigures, you can do that yourself.)

Comment: @JohnKormylo for the moment, I'm not concerned about aligning the captions. I've tried using `tabular`, but to no avail so far--it also aligns at the *baseline*. The tricky part is aligning with regards to other objects

Comment: If you replace subfigure with minipage it works fine.  They are easy enough to dispense with.

Comment: I just noticed your bonus.  That is very generous of you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here I introduce `\pushfigure[alignment]{width}{content}{captioningof}` to push figures onto a "stack", and then `\popfigures` to  set them all on a line.  In all cases, captioning should be done with `\captionof` for any figure being "pushed".  Bottom alignment is the default.

The `\pushfigure` phase of the operation saves all the parameters, and measures the height (plus any depth) of the `content`.  It saves the maximum height+depth of all the contents that have been pushed.

The `\popfigures` phase performs a `\stackinset` of the figure atop a rule of the maximum-content-height, using the saved alignment for the figure.  This achieves proper vertical alignment of the figures.  Any captioning that was specified is applied below the vertical `\rule`, which will keep all captions at the same height, regardless of content alignment.

An `\hfill` is inserted at the beginning and after each figure popped.  All parameters (counters/lengths) are reset at the end of the "pop", to prepare for the next sequence of "push"es.

For this MWE, I reduced the value of `\abovecaptionskip` to 6pt, which I find more visually pleasing when employing subfigures.

EDITED to demonstrate `tabular` and `\parbox` content.  REEDITED to account for the fact that bottom aligned `tabular` and `\parbox` boxes can still have depth, associated with descending letters on the bottom line.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe=true,textwidth=12cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{stackengine,ifthen}
\newcounter{figstack}
\newcounter{figindex}
\newlength\fight
\newcommand\pushfigure[4][b]{%
  \stepcounter{figstack}%
  \expandafter\def\csname %
    figalign\romannumeral\value{figstack}\endcsname{#1}%
  \expandafter\def\csname %
    figwd\romannumeral\value{figstack}\endcsname{#2}%
  \expandafter\def\csname %
    figcontent\romannumeral\value{figstack}\endcsname{#3}%
  \expandafter\def\csname %
    figcap\romannumeral\value{figstack}\endcsname{#4}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{%
    \begin{minipage}{#2}#3\end{minipage}}%
  \ifdim\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax>\fight\global\setlength{\fight}{%
    \dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax}\fi%
}
\newcommand\popfigures{%
  \setcounter{figindex}{0}%
  \hfill%
  \whiledo{\value{figindex}<\value{figstack}}{%
    \stepcounter{figindex}%
    \def\tmp{\csname figwd\romannumeral\value{figindex}\endcsname}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\tmp}%
      \centering%
      \stackinset{c}{}%
        {\csname figalign\romannumeral\value{figindex}\endcsname}{}%
        {\csname figcontent\romannumeral\value{figindex}\endcsname}%
        {\rule{0pt}{\fight}}\par%
      \csname figcap\romannumeral\value{figindex}\endcsname%
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill%
  }%
  \setcounter{figstack}{0}%
  \setlength{\fight}{0pt}%
  \hfill%
}
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{6pt}
\begin{document}
\pushfigure{.1\textwidth}
           {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
           {\captionof{figure}{}}
\pushfigure[t]{.15\textwidth}
           {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
           {\captionof{figure}{}}
\pushfigure[t]{.2\textwidth}
           {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}}%
           {}
\pushfigure[c]{.1\textwidth}
           {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}}%
           {}
\pushfigure[c]{.2\textwidth}
           {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}}%
           {}
\noindent\popfigures

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\captionsetup{labelformat=parens}
  \pushfigure[t]{.1\textwidth}
             {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
             {\captionof{subfigure}{}}
  \pushfigure{.15\textwidth}
%             {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
             {\begin{tabular}[b]{ccc}a&b&c\\dd&e&fff\\%
               a&b&c\\x&yy& z\end{tabular}}
             {\captionof{subfigure}{}}
\popfigures\par
\captionsetup{labelformat=default}
\caption{}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\captionsetup{labelformat=parens}
  \pushfigure[c]{.1\textwidth}
             {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
             {\captionof{subfigure}{}}
  \pushfigure[c]{.15\textwidth}
%             {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
             {\parbox{\textwidth}{%
                This is text and a bit more text and some more text}}
             {\captionof{subfigure}{}}
\popfigures\par
\captionsetup{labelformat=default}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**VERSION FOR TABLES**

Directly analogous to figure version, but with `\poptables` (sub)captions placed above the figures.  Note, though, that if table captions are multiline, the captions will be bottom-aligned with respect to other captions in the same row.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe=true,textwidth=12cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{stackengine,ifthen}
\newcounter{tblstack}
\newcounter{tblindex}
\newlength\tblht
\newcommand\pushtable[4][b]{%
  \stepcounter{tblstack}%
  \expandafter\def\csname %
    tblalign\romannumeral\value{tblstack}\endcsname{#1}%
  \expandafter\def\csname %
    tblwd\romannumeral\value{tblstack}\endcsname{#2}%
  \expandafter\def\csname %
    tblcontent\romannumeral\value{tblstack}\endcsname{#3}%
  \expandafter\def\csname %
    tblcap\romannumeral\value{tblstack}\endcsname{#4}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{%
    \begin{minipage}{#2}#3\end{minipage}}%
  \ifdim\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax>\tblht\global\setlength{\tblht}{%
    \dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax}\fi%
}
\newcommand\poptables{%
  \setcounter{tblindex}{0}%
  \hfill%
  \whiledo{\value{tblindex}<\value{tblstack}}{%
    \stepcounter{tblindex}%
    \def\tmp{\csname tblwd\romannumeral\value{tblindex}\endcsname}%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\tmp}%
      \centering%
      \csname tblcap\romannumeral\value{tblindex}\endcsname\par%
      \stackinset{c}{}%
        {\csname tblalign\romannumeral\value{tblindex}\endcsname}{}%
        {\csname tblcontent\romannumeral\value{tblindex}\endcsname}%
        {\rule{0pt}{\tblht}}%
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill%
  }%
  \setcounter{tblstack}{0}%
  \setlength{\tblht}{0pt}%
  \hfill%
}
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{6pt}
\begin{document}
\pushtable{.1\textwidth}
           {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
           {\captionof{table}{}}
\pushtable[t]{.15\textwidth}
           {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
           {\captionof{table}{}}
\pushtable[t]{.2\textwidth}
           {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}}%
           {}
\pushtable[c]{.1\textwidth}
           {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}}%
           {}
\pushtable[c]{.2\textwidth}
           {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}}%
           {}
\noindent\poptables

\bigskip\begin{table}[!htb]
\captionsetup{labelformat=default}
\caption{}
\captionsetup{labelformat=parens}
  \pushtable[t]{.1\textwidth}
             {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
             {\captionof{subtable}{}}
  \pushtable{.15\textwidth}
%             {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
             {\begin{tabular}[b]{ccc}a&b&c\\dd&e&fff\\%
               a&b&c\\x&yy& z\end{tabular}}
             {\captionof{subtable}{}}
\poptables\par
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\captionsetup{labelformat=default}
\caption{}
\captionsetup{labelformat=parens}
  \pushtable[c]{.1\textwidth}
             {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
             {\captionof{subtable}{}}
  \pushtable[c]{.15\textwidth}
%             {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
             {\parbox{\textwidth}{%
                This is text and a bit more text and some more text}}
             {\captionof{subtable}{}}
\poptables\par
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Now the tricky part is if one wants table and figures on the same row.  The macro `\popfigures` achieves its vertical alignment by using top-aligned minipages.  The `\poptables` does it by using bottom-aligned minipages.  Neither of these approaches will work if a row must accommodate both top and bottom captioning.

That problem has not yet been solved.

Comment: Very clever solution!

Comment: Very, very nice, thank you :) The algorithm you've used makes perfect sense--my original plan was to write to the `aux` file, but you've shown that it isn't necessary, brilliant! I might not have mentioned that I'd like this to be able to handle text as well; e.g `\pushfigure[t]{.1\textwidth}{here is some text here \par is some text here is some text here is some text}`, but this doesn't seem to work... Is there an easy fix? Thanks again!

Comment: @cmhughes I made a revision so as to handle that is not the same width as the specified width.  But to answer your particular question, `\parbox` and `tabular` data are quite amenable as `content`.  Please see revision.  The key is that `content`, being inside a `minipage` of a specified `width`, needs to be itself constrained to a width (usually `\textwidth`, which will occupy the full `minipage`).

Comment: @cmhughes typo: *I made a revision so as to handle **content** that is not the same width as the specified width.*

Comment: @cmhughes I revised again to account for descender-induced box depth of `tabular` and `\parbox` content.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you for all of your time on this :) I think you've presented some very clean, logical code that should scale into my project. I'd like to allow the possibility for the `caption` to go above the object, but I should be able to create another argument for `pushfigure` that could be `top` or `bottom` (I'm not asking you to work on it `:)`). Thanks again, I very much appreciate you taking the time to look and work on this.

Comment: @cmhughes  Not that I can accomodate, but would you want top & bottom captions on a single row, or always top **or** bottom captions on a given row?  Also, would your desire for top captions be to have the captions be aligned at the top with each other on the same row, or at the bottom of the caption?

Comment: @cmhughes The reason I ask is that I forsee some difficulties if you want some items on a row with top and other with bottom captions.  As it is, I use a top-aligned `minipage` for each popped figure, so captions below don't hose it up.  If all captions in a row were top captions, I could likewise use a bottom-aligned `minipage`.  But with mixed top/bottom captions in a row, some added alignment logic would be required.

Comment: Indeed, it'll be tricky to align some objects with captions on top, and some with captions underneath... I'll have a look and see if I can work it out, otherwise I'll ask a new question--you've gone above and beyond what I originally asked, and for that, I'm very grateful; thank you :)

Comment: Sorry to trouble you, Steven... I tried referencing a `subfigure` element, and it produces the wrong figure number--any ideas?

Comment: @cmhughes Let me have a look, though nothing obvious jumps out at me.

Comment: I don't think it's unique to your solution, so don't worry too much; I think it's a result of using `captionof` with `subfigure`; the same is true with a mwe, as in Harish's answer here: [Placing two figures (each having subfigures) next two each other](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78760)

Comment: @cmhughes I was thinking that the issue was not unique to me.  The only kludge I have is `\def\xfcaptionof#1#2{%
  \refstepcounter{figure}%
  \captionof{#1}{#2}%
  \addtocounter{figure}{-1}%
}` to be used when needed.

Answer (score 4):

The subcaption package is doing something dodgy.  For example, you can't use \captionof{subfigure} inside a subfigure (anywhere else is fine).

I overcame the problems of my previous solution by permanently replacing subfigure with minipage and creating my own \caption from scratch.

[image: sideways tabular]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe=true,textwidth=12cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{environ}

\newlength{\reservemaxheight}
\newcommand{\oldcaption}{}% reserve name
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newcaption}[2][\@empty]{% same as caption
  \refstepcounter{subfigure}%
  \ifx#1\@empty\addcontentsline{lof}{subfigure}{\hbox to\@tempdima {\thesubfigure\hfil }{\ignorespaces #2}}%
  \else\addcontentsline{lof}{subfigure}{\hbox to\@tempdima {\thesubfigure\hfil }{\ignorespaces #1}}%
  \fi
  \rule{0pt}{1.5\baselineskip}(\thesubfigure) #2}
\makeatother

\def\newsubfigure{\let\oldcaption=\caption
  \let\caption=\newcaption
  \minipage}%
\def\endnewsubfigure{\endminipage
  \let\caption=\oldcaption}%
\AtBeginDocument{% can't replace it any earlier
  \let\subfigure=\newsubfigure
  \let\endsubfigure=\endnewsubfigure}

\newsavebox{\vabox}
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{verticallyaligned}{%
    % temporarily set \vamaxheight to nothing during the measurements
    \let\vamaxheight\relax
    % temporarily disable figure numbering
    \savecounters@
    % measure the height of the body
    \begin{lrbox}{\vabox}
        \BODY%
    \end{lrbox}%
    % turn figure numbering back on
    \restorecounters@
    % set the height of the minipage box
    \let\vamaxheight\reservemaxheight
    \setlength{\vamaxheight}{\ht\vabox}%
    \addtolength{\vamaxheight}{-\dp\vabox}% change back to positive
    % output the body, which now contains the new height :)
    \noindent\makebox[\linewidth][c]{\mbox{}\hfill\BODY\hfill\mbox{}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{verticallyaligned}
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}[b][\vamaxheight][b]{.10\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \captionof{figure}{}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b][\vamaxheight][t]{.15\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \captionof{figure}{}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b][\vamaxheight][t]{.20\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b][\vamaxheight][c]{.10\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b][\vamaxheight][t]{.20\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{minipage}%
\end{verticallyaligned}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \begin{verticallyaligned}
        \begin{subfigure}[b][\vamaxheight][t]{.10\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{test}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b][\vamaxheight][t]{.15\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption[short caption]{long caption}
        \end{subfigure}%
    \end{verticallyaligned}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \begin{verticallyaligned}
        \begin{subfigure}[b][\vamaxheight][c]{.10\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b][\vamaxheight][c]{.15\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{}
        \end{subfigure}%
    \end{verticallyaligned}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}
\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

Comment: The 4th figure in the top row does not appear to be center aligned.  Am I seeing that right?

Comment: The largest minipage in the top row is B, including the caption, so the 4th figure is centered with that (including the caption).  The interesting thing is that A is supposed to be bottom aligned with B, but is obviously lower.

Comment: If you want I can redo this using total heights and \raisebox, or even aligning the captions separately.  I thought you just wanted to fix the caption numbers.

Comment: I see.  I had not thought about aligning *including the captions* (in my answer, the captions are not part of the vertical-alignment calculation).  Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: If they are in the minipage, they will be counted.

Comment: Great work, thank you very much for looking at my question :)